# progressBar in mode indeterminate with Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to implemate a *progressBar* in mode *indeterminate* but it's doesnt work. I was reading the documentation, but never says something about mode indeterminate. This example there is in the web, and if I copy and paste, it works the rest, but indeterminate  dont.

```
<h3>Indeterminate</h3>
    <p:progressBar id="progressBarIndeterminate" style="height:6px" mode="indeterminate"/>
```

Comment: Whats PrimeFaces version do you use? The "mode" attribute is introduced in Version 6.2

Comment: @Ovoxo I have 6.1 Thanks, I will download 6.2

Comment: @Ovoxo it works THANKS :)

Comment: You're Welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the version of Primefaces. This mode works with min version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as they already commented you have to be on Primefaces version 6.2+

If you are already updated with the version try setting the **width**!

```
 <div class="ui-g-12">
   <p:progressBar id="progressBarIndeterminate" style="width:100%; height:6px"
                                       mode="indeterminate"/>
 </div>
```

The only thing that they forgot is to **specify the width** while givving it for testing.
Please specify a width and check it again. I tried it and as you can see the results are perfect.

[testing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUppg.png)

Comment: One reason might be the version and the other might be the width  of the element. So i just updated the answer so to help the others that will come here and search for potential problem. I had the same issue, i was updated but still the bar wasn't showing and i found out that the width did the job. I suppose that Luis that made the question at first has the bar element inside a div that the container passes the width so he didn't face the second side problem that i am trying to prevent with my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Good improvement and comment.